# Can't "select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"

Tags: secure-boot

Im getting an issue where whenever I boot up it says "reboot and select proper boot device." Many people have this issue and the solution is to turn on secure boot and do something "select an UEFI file as trusted for executing." But whenever I boot in secure mode or not, I never get that option in the security tab of the BIOS.